# How to list only item containing string X in a string Y from a dictionnary in Jinja2

Tags: templates, jinja2

I’m trying to obtain the count of all title containing a specific string from a dictionary in a jinja template.

I have tried many variant with select and other test and haven’t found the right way to do so.
This is not for ansible for which I have found many solutions to fix this issue.
Also the test equalto does not work since I do not have an exact match on the string and doesn’t seem to take regex.

```
{{ Dictionnary | selectattr("title", "in","MyString") | list | count }}
```

It seems that the string never gets properly evaluated because it always returns 0.
The selectattr without test return the right number of total titles.

I wonder if we could evaluate it with an if statement somehow.